# Sound produced by spacebar on MBP 15" (mid-2017) non-symmetrical

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

When rapidly pressing the left area of the keyboard (directly under C,V,B,N keys) of the QWERTY keyboard on the mid-2017 MacBook Pro 15", the sound produced is different than pressing the right edge of the keyboard (under the M key). Simply put, the left side produces a louder sound which seems to occur higher up in the keyboard, where the right edge sounds like the normal alpha-numeric keys where the sound seems to originate further down. Is this an issue solely with my computer, or does it occur with every MBP?

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard on the 2016 and 2017 mbp is prone to getting sticky, soft and even unresponsive keys. Usually caused by dust or dirt under the key caps.

Try cleaning the keyboard as mentioned in apple's support files: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205662

Comment: Can you confirm there is no nuance in sound depending on where you press on the keyboard?

Comment: By default no, but i must admit that at all times there is at least one key on my keyboard (late-2016 MacBook Pro 15) that makes a uneven sound. If its a problem contact Apple support, but you can also wait a week and see if the sound is still uneven after some days of use.